# How to do multiple check option in React js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, lodash

Basically i'm having two kind of arrays. One for all checkbox values and another one for custom values. So, my requirement is i want to be get selected the values from custom array value by default to the checkbox options. How to implement with reactjs?

This is my sample code,

```
var optionArray = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7'], selectedValue = ['item1', 'item5'];

var Items = optionArray.map(function(el, i){
var isChecked = el == selectedValue;
                return <div key={i} className="radio-tick-row">
                    <input type="checkbox" className="radio-tick-input" id={"option"+i} value={el} name="selectOrganisationType" onChange={self.onChange.bind(self)} checked={isChecked} />
                    <label className="checkbox-tick-label term" htmlFor={"option"+i}><span>{el}</span></label>
                </div>;
        });
```

Comment: You mean to map inside of that existing map function?

Comment: @OriDrori. can you please update the demo code?

Comment: No. I want to display all optionArray values. I don't want to remove. Only that selected values option should get selected.

Comment: Got you. I've removed the other comments, and added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a if in array condition:

```
var optionArray = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7'], selectedValue = ['item1', 'item5'];

var Items = optionArray.map(function(el, i){
var isChecked = false;
                if(selectedValue.indexOf(el)) {
                   isChecked = true;
                 }
                return <div key={i} className="radio-tick-row">
                    <input type="checkbox" className="radio-tick-input" id={"option"+i} value={el} name="selectOrganisationType" onChange={self.onChange.bind(self)} defaultChecked={isChecked} />
                    <label className="checkbox-tick-label term" htmlFor={"option"+i}><span>{el}</span></label>
                </div>;
        });
```

Comment: It is not working. All options get selected on first time itself.

Comment: i have one more doubt. If my selectedValue is null. I will get that value some other places while firing on change events. How to control if it is null on initial state?

Comment: add another if to test if selectedValue  is null

Comment: right now it will not affect your code if the selectedValue  is null

Answer (score 0):

For better view as well as ES 20's

```
const Items = optionArray.map((el, i) => {
  const isChecked = selectedValue.indexOf(el) > -1;
  return (
    <div key={i} className="radio-tick-row">
      <input type="checkbox" className="radio-tick-input" id={"option"+i}
         value={el} name="selectOrganisationType"
         onChange={self.onChange.bind(self)} checked={isChecked} />
      <label className="checkbox-tick-label term" htmlFor={"option"+i}>
        <span>{el}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```
var optionArray = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7'], selectedValue = ['item1', 'item5'];

var selectedValueSet = new Set(selectedValue);

var Items = optionArray.map(function(el, i){
    var isChecked = selectedValueSet.has(el);
    return (
        <div key={i} className="radio-tick-row">
            <input type="checkbox" className="radio-tick-input" id={"option"+i} value={el} name="selectOrganisationType" onChange={self.onChange.bind(self)} checked={isChecked} />
            <label className="checkbox-tick-label term" htmlFor={"option"+i}><span>{el}</span></label>
        </div>
    );
});
```